# Are there any polynomials $P(x)$ that will always contain a prime factor larger than $x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I'm looking for a function $P(x)=a_1 x^{b_1}+a_2 x^{b_2}+\ldots+1$ such that for any positive integer $x$ input, there is guaranteed to be a prime factor $p>x$ which divides $P(x)$. For instance, although $f(x):=x^2+1$ is not such a polynomial, it usually has the behavior I'm looking for where e.g. $5^2+1=2 \cdot 13$ and $13>5$.

This is trivially easy to do with factorials or primorials, of course. Unless I am mistaken this is also the case for $2^n-1$ and similar exponential expressions. Presumably that includes various recurrence relations built along the same mechanism.

Anyway, are there any polynomials that have this property? If not, also welcome are other function classes which do have it.

Comment: It's unclear for what $x$ you want this to hold. At least one? Infinitely many? For all?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. $f(x)=a$ seems like a constant function. Do you mean a function $f$ such that for every prime $p$ there exists some $x$ such that $p$ divides $f(x)$=

Comment: I'm sorry, I have a bad habit of that. Hopefully this edit is clearer.

Comment: Do you know the random model for the primes ? With $Lpf(m)$ the largest prime factor of $m$, it says when we choose $m$ in $[1,M]$ uniformly then

$Pr(Lpf(m)<m^{1/k})\approx \prod_{p \in [m^{1/k},m]} (1-\frac1{\log p})\approx \exp(-\sum_{k \in [m^{1/k},m]}\frac{1}{\log^2 k})\approx \exp(\frac{m^{1/k}}{\log^2 m^{1/k}}-\frac{m}{\log^2 m})$ thus $\prod_m (1-Pr(Lpf(m)<m^{1/k}))$ converges almost surely. It means for a non-trivial polynomial $f(n)$, it is almost surely that there is some $N$ such that for all $n\ge N, Lpf(f(n))> n$.

Comment: any polynomial in $x$ divisible by $2x+1$ for a general factor.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee How do you mean? Irreducible polynomials, like $x^2+1$ aren't divisible by anything in general. Also I'm looking for an integer value larger than $x$ to come out as a result.

Comment: okay fine I guess I suck.